# List of Journey Builder Activities on production account

Tags: marketing-cloud, activities

Can you provide us a screenshot or list of Jouner Builder Activities? We need to know full functionality of **production account** in order to know what do we need to develop... Currently, our **development account** has:

Messages

```
Send Email
```

Split

```
Decision Split
Random Split
Engagement Split
```

Customer Updates

```
Update Contact Data
```

Is this the defintive list? Or, when we purchase a **production account**, we are going to have at least same activities like in Automation Studio?

Please help us. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activities you currently see in your Development environment are the same ones available in a Production environment.

Custom activities can also be built but would not mimic those that exist in Automation Studio.  Examples of Custom Activities include, but are not limited to, custom messaging through uncommon channels or custom data update activities like an evaluation of only specified data fields on Contact records. Your ExactTarget Relationship Manager would be the best resource to discuss any custom solutions you might need.

[image: Activities in a Production Account]

See below for a quick link on the Activities that make up an Interaction in Journey Builder:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/